# $x^{8} - x^{4} + 1 = 0$ solve and write the roots of the equation in trigonometric form

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve [my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NbBw.jpg) and write the roots of the equation in trigonometric form.I can not find a solution, I will be glad to help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried to substitution $y=x^4$?

Comment: You tagged your question with `complex-numbers`, so you know you are looking for complex solutions. Then why does your attempt say "$\left(x^2 - \sqrt{3}/2\right)^2 \ne -1/4$"?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia the attempt is handwritten in the link

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please take a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/947379) to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @dxiv,THANK YOU SOMETHING I WAS CONFUSED WHEN I SOLVED THE EQUATION. BELOW I SHOWED HOW TO SOLVE AN EQUATION BY REPLACEMENT OF A VARIABLE, BUT IF I CONTINUE MY SOLUTION IS THE SAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP has shown work, and the only issue is MathJax, I can transplant my comment/guides into a solution.

As the answer of polite proofs indicates, the first step is to convert the equation

$$z^8 - z^4 + 1 = 0 ~~\text{into}~~ a^2 - a + 1 = 0 ~: ~a = z^4.  \tag1 $$

In (1) above, I follow the convention of using $z$ rather than $x$ to indicate complex variables.  This facilitates setting $z = (x + iy) ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}.$

---

The next step is to solve the equation in (1) above. 
Using the formula for quadratic equations:

$$a = \frac{1}{2}~ \left[ ~1 ~\pm ~\sqrt{1 - 4} ~\right] ~=~ \frac{1}{2} ~\left[ ~1 ~\pm ~i ~\sqrt{3} ~\right].$$

Denoting the two solutions to (1) above as $S$ and $T$,
you have that

$$S = \left[\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right], ~~
T = \left[\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right]. \tag2 $$

---

The next step is to convert each of these solutions into polar coordinates.  The following generic procedure may be followed to convert any **non-zero** complex number $(x + iy)$ into the form $re^{i\theta} ~: ~r \in \Bbb{R^+}, 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi.$

Note: In the above paragraph, the term **non-zero** refers to the constraint that you can not have $x$ and $y$ **both** equal to $(0)$.

- First, calculate $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \implies 0 < r.$
- Then, calculate $~\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}$.
- Then, calculate $~\displaystyle \sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}$.

Then, determine $\theta$ as the unique angle such that $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ and $\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)$ are as described above.

Typically, this determination will have two forms:

- Either, you will identify the unique value of $\theta$, explicitly.
- Or, you will identify $\theta$ by simply referring to the values of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta).$

---

Implementing the procedure in the previous section, with respect to $S$, you have that :

$$r = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2} = 1.$$

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1} = \frac{1}{2},
~~ \sin(\theta) = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

The specific angle $\theta$ with the pertinent cosine and sine values is $\theta = \pi/3$ (i.e. AKA $60^\circ$).

Therefore,

$$S = 1 \times e^{i\pi/3} = e^{i(\pi/3)}.\tag3 $$

In a very similar fashion, you have that

$$T = e^{i(5\pi/3)}. \tag4 $$

---

The next step is to use the following theorem in elementary Complex Analysis:

$$r_1e^{i\theta_1} \times r_2e^{i\theta_2} = \left(r_1r_2\right) e^{i\left(\theta_1 + \theta_2\right)}. \tag{Theorem 1}$$

As a corollary to (Theorem 1) above you have
that :

$$\textbf{One of the roots to} ~z^n = re^{i\theta} \tag{DeMoivre's Theorem} $$

$$\textbf{is} ~r^{(1/n)}e^{i(\theta/n)}.$$

Let me know if you are unable to prove Theorem 1 and/or (my version of) DeMoivre's Theorem.  If needed, I will add an Addendum to my answer, with the proofs.

---

Once a specific root $r^{(1/n)}e^{i(\theta/n)}$ is found, you then want to find all of the **other** $(n-1)$ roots.
These may be found by simply multiplying the root that you found to each of the $n$ roots of $z^n = 1.$

The $n$ roots of $z^n = 1$ are given by

$$e^{i\left(2k\pi/n\right)} ~: k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$$

The remainder of this answer implements the above procedure against the two values $S,T$ shown in (3) and (4) above.

---

The two values $S,T$ shown in (3) and (4) above, represent the two possible solutions to the variable $a$, where $a$ represents $z^4$.

I will let the primary root of $z^4 = S$, be represented by $s_1$, and the other three roots be represented by $s_2, s_3, s_4$.

I will let the primary root of $z^4 = T$, be represented by $t_1$, and the other three roots be represented by $t_2, t_3, t_4$.

This means that the final answer will be the polar coordinates of the elements in the set $$\{s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4\}.$$

$\displaystyle S = e^{i(\pi/3)} \implies s_1 = e^{i(\pi/12)}.$ 
$\displaystyle s_2 = s_1 \times e^{i(\pi/2)} = e^{i[(\pi/12) + (\pi/2)]} = e^{i(7\pi/12)}.$ 
Similarly, $~\displaystyle s_3 = s_1 \times e^{i(\pi)} = e^{i[(\pi/12) + (\pi)]} = e^{i(13\pi/12)}.$ 
Similarly, $~\displaystyle s_4 = s_1 \times e^{i(3\pi/2)} = e^{i[(\pi/12) + (3\pi/2)]} = e^{i(19\pi/12)}.$

$\displaystyle T = e^{i(5\pi/3)} \implies t_1 = e^{i(5\pi/12)}.$ 
$\displaystyle t_2 = t_1 \times e^{i(\pi/2)} = e^{i[(5\pi/12) + (\pi/2)]} = e^{i(11\pi/12)}.$ 
$\displaystyle t_3 = t_1 \times e^{i(\pi)} = e^{i[(5\pi/12) + (\pi)]} = e^{i(17\pi/12)}.$ 
$\displaystyle t_4 = t_1 \times e^{i(3\pi/2)} = e^{i[(5\pi/12) + (3\pi/2)]} = e^{i(23\pi/12)}.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $a = x^4$. Then we have $a^2 - a + 1 = 0$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos To me, it seems like the OP already attempted some work, however I believe they over-complicated it and there is a much simpler solution available. Thus, I give a hint for the OP.

Comment: No, the OP didn't even take his time to type the question with MathJax, and also did not show what he has tried, or what he can use. So no effort really.

Comment: The OP's attempt is in the link, and it seems thorough to me.  The only issue (to my mind) is that the OP used a link rather than learning MathJax.

Comment: @politeproofs Thanks for the tip. Changing the variable makes the solution easier.